# How to update parent component view when data is fetched from child component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, viewchild

I have a parent and a child component, the child component is actually a modal where we can enter emails and click on 'Add to List'.
The entered emails are then fetched from parent component using @ViewChild property. The array details are obtained in parent because I can console.log() and see them from parent.

But how do I update a part of view in Parent with this new data is received ?

The code and explanations are as below :

**Child component :**

"emails" is an array with email ids.
I am fetching this array from child.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-student-popup',
  templateUrl: './add-student-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-student-popup.component.scss']
})


export class AddStudentPopupComponent implements OnInit {
  emails: string[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  **** Some other code that adds user entered emails to an array 'emails' ****
  ----
  ----

  sendData() {
    console.log(this.emails);
  }

}
```

**Parent**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// Add students modal popup
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from  'ngx-bootstrap/modal/';
import { AddStudentPopupComponent } from './add-student-popup/add-student-popup.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-course',
  templateUrl: './create-course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-course.component.scss']
})

export class CreateCourseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  bsModalRef!: BsModalRef;
  emails: string[] = [];
  isEmpty: boolean = true;

  @ViewChild(AddStudentPopupComponent) addStudent!: AddStudentPopupComponent;

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }

  ngOnInit(): any {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.addStudent) {
      this.emails = this.addStudent.emails;
      isEmpty = false;
    }
  }

  openAddStudentModal() {
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(AddStudentPopupComponent, {class: 'modal-lg'});
    this.bsModalRef.content.closeBtnName = 'Close';
  }

}
```

I want to use the updated "emails" array in my front end view. The view part using this array should be updated.

**View part**

When the popup is filled and submitted the emails array is populated and it should update the this view part.

```
<div class="multipleInput-container" *ngIf="!isEmpty;else noEmails">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul *ngFor="let email of emails">
            <li class="multipleInput-email">{{ email }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<ng-template #noEmails>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
            placeholder="No Students Added" aria-label="No Students Added">
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@Output`

In `AddStudentPopupComponent`

```js
   emails: string[] = [];
   @Output() sendEmail = new EventEmitter();
   sendData() {
      this.sendEmail.emit(this.emails);
   }
```

then in `create-course.component.html` file

```html
<app-add-student-popup (sendEmail)="emails = $event"></app-add-student-popup>
```

Comment: I used a similar approach using event emitters and was able to update the view. Thanks for the help